# Get lazy list ordered by column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

This is my simple situation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<Author> authors;

    public List<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
}

public class DAO {

    public void getOrderedAuthorsByProject(Project project) {
        return project.getAuthors(); // Line 1
    }
}
```

In the line 1, how return the author list, ordered by specific column of Author entity, simply doing a get?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property you wish to sort on is a field in Author (i.e. is a column in the Authors table) then you can use @OrderBy:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
@OrderBy("surname, forename asc")
private List<Author> authors;
```

If it was a nested property then you can use the (Hibernate specific, non JPA) `@Sort` annotation to do an in-memory sort. You can either specify a Comparator or specify SortType = NATURAL if your Author entity implements the Comparable interface.

http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-collections-hibernate